# Convert XML file to a named list in R

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar>
    <add key="key1" value="value1" />
    <add key="key2" value="value2" />
  </bar>
</foo>
```

And I want to end up with a list `foobar` were I can call the values like `foobar$key1` and it will return the string value `"value1"`. What I have so far is

```
library(XML)
foobar.xml=xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse('foobar.xml')) 
foobar=sapply(foobar.xml$children$bar$children,FUN=function(x){
    key=x$attributes["key"]
    value=x$attributes["value"]
    names(value)=key
    return(value)
})
```

but this isn't right because the returned object is an atomic vector whose elements have names like `add.key1` rather than a list with elements named like `key1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `XML` package as you did,

```
foobar <- list()
for(x in foobar.xml$children$bar$children) {

     key=x$attributes["key"]
     value=x$attributes["value"]
     foobar[[key]] <- value 
}
```

or by using `xml2`,

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

myxml <- read_xml( "./desktop/data.xml" )

key <- xml_find_all( myxml, "//add") %>% xml_attr("key")
value <- xml_find_all( myxml, "//add") %>% xml_attr("value")

foobar <- list()
for( i in 1:length(key)) {

    foobar[[key[i]]] <- value[i]    

}
```